# server IP address of my website rather than domain IP

Tags: php, web, ip, payment-gateway

Hi I need to know the IP address of my website to give to my payment gateway. I know I can find an IP address by going to any of the websites which come up on google, but my understanding is that they give the domain's IP address which may be different from the IP address of the server the site is hosted on.

So how to I find out what the IP address of my server is?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run this from the command line to get your server's outgoing IP:

`wget -q -O - checkip.dyndns.org|sed -e 's/.*Current IP Address: //' -e 's/<.*$//'`

Answer (score 0):

The server's IP address can be found with the [`$_SERVER`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) variable:

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];
```

Comment: Be careful! `$_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']` may list your LAN IP rather than your public IP

Comment: This produces a different result from I was expecting. I know what the value is meant to be but I get a different one using SERVER_ADDR

Answer (score 0):

you can also do a quick PHP output of

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

it will contain all the values you need for your host details (just don't leave this file public after you use it).

Comment: I've tried this but it doesn't have the IP address I'm expecting to see. I have a file which a developer gave me which prints out the contents of a file on his website, it gives me the IP address I need but I can't figure out what's in the file!?!? And I don't want to ask him!

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by the domain IP? The IP returned from a DNS lookup when querying your domain? This is most likely equal to the IP of your (shared) server, otherwise your website would be unreachable.

An exception to that is when the IP your DNS record represents belongs to a proxy server, which forwards the request to the real server.

You could always get the public IP address of the server by visiting [www.whatismyip.com](http://www.whatismyip.com/) from the server.

Comment: How do I visit www.whatismyip.com from the server? I have ftp access, is there something I can do with that?

Comment: @ZaphodBeeblebrox take a look at CURL.